# How to filter one data object at each hour for each day in a given data range in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

Here is a snippet of json object,I am trying to get one json object for each hour from 1/1 to 3/31.
assume there are some JSON object have time 01/01/2020 12:00 ,01/01/2020 13:00   and so on. I only want to get these json object for each day. So there supposed to have 24 json object for each day. I know how to filter array of element base on one static condition, but I am not sure how to do it when the condition is dynamic.

```
[
  {
    "id": 2617820,
    "time": "01/01/2020 12:16",
    "stationId": "150000",
    "RoadStatus": "Ice",
    "surfaceRoadTemperature": "30.9F",

  },
  {
    "id": 2617819,
    "time": "01/01/2020 12:26",
    "stationId": "150000",
    "RoadStatus": "Ice",
    "surfaceRoadTemperature": "30.7F",
  },
  {
    "id": 2617818,
    "time": "01/01/2020 12:30",
    "stationId": "150000",
    "RoadStatus": "Ice",
    "surfaceRoadTemperature": "30.9F",

  },
  {
    "id": 2617817,
    "time": "01/01/2020 12:36",
    "stationId": "150000",
    "RoadStatus": "Ice",
    "surfaceRoadTemperature": "30.7F",

  }
]
```

Comment: 1. I don't see exact hours in the JSON object - should we assume there are - are those you want - what about the others: 12:16, 12:26, 12:30, etc. - or, just pick one?!?

Comment: 2. You used 24-hour format in your question - excellent!  (13:00) - May I recommend using Date format that is used everywhere in the whole world (except a small part of the north part of one of the seven continents - USA...) as Day-Of-Month, Month, Year (31/3 instead of the "wrong" 3/31...  When is the "4th of July" (correct)? - "July 4th" (just silly :) ))?

Comment: 3. Do you want one occurrence or do you want an update every hour (on the hour or hourly since page load)?

Answer (score 1):

You mention Array.filter() so I will assume you might want a functional style answer. Have you tried Array.reduce().

`arr.reduce(callback( accumulator, currentValue[, index[, array]] )[, initialValue])` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

In your case the callback be something like

```
function addHourif(acc, cv){
const prevtime = new Date(acc.slice(-1)[0].time).getTime()
const cvtime = new Date(cv.time).getTime()

if (cvtime >= prevtime + 60*60*1000 ) return [...acc , cv]
else return acc
}

console.log(a.reduce(addHourif, [a[0]]))
```

This worked on your data if I changed the hours, this just checks if an hour has passed since the last entry, you could use the Date methods to refine the process so you get the nearest one to an hour or exactly 24 per day etc...